# Xlib fullscreen on multi monitors

Tags: fullscreen, xlib

I have some troubles with multi-monitor configurations and xlib fullscreen windows. It is possible to detect which screen on virtual desktop contains window and window sizes when it goes to fullscreen (when sending _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN)?
I have two monitors 1024x768 combined into big desktop 2048x768, Xinerama correctly reports two 1024x768 screens, but WM can raise window into only one screen or both screens (enabling/disabling in WM settings). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found solution. It is so easy: catch ConfigureNotify event while pending display.